# How to create multiple references to a single footnote in ConTeXt?

Tags: footnotes, context, context-mkiv

I have some footnotes in a ConTeXt document, which must be referenced too multiple times, i.e., the superscript mark `1` appears in several parts of the document, but the footnote is only displayed once, e.g.:

```
This is some text.^1

^1 This is the footnote text.

This is some more text.^1
```

With the stable edition of ConTeXt, this syntax worked:

```
\setupfootnotes[location=text]
\starttext
    This is some text.\note[footnote][1]
        \setnotetext[footnote][1]{This is the footnote text.}
        \placefootnotes
    This is some more text.\note[footnote][1]
\stopfootnote
```

With the current edition of ConTeXt, `\setnotetext` seems to correctly place the notes, however, `\note` seems no longer able to refer to my notes. After compiling, I get:

```
This is some text.^??

^1 This is the footnote text.

This is some more text.^??
```

I also tried the instructions found at the ConTeXt Garden article on [footnotes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Footnotes#Alternate_Footnote_Locations), but the resulting compilation also creates `??` instead of numbering.

How can I create multiple references to a single footnote in the current version of ConTeXt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, using `\footnote` and `\note` in any order:

```
This is some text.\footnote[footnote]{This is the footnote text.}

This is some more text.\note[footnote]
```

This leaves the specification of the footnote symbol to ConTeXt. If you want to specify the number yourself, look at [`\defineconversion`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/defineconversion)

```
\defineconversion[myset][list of comma separated symbols]
\setupnotation[footnote][way=bypage,numberconversion=myset]
```

Does this solve your problem, or does some more specific use still not work?

Comment: That was with ConTeXt 2012? I tried just what you did by intuition (in current ConTeXt, 2013), but is still showing ?? instead of the footnote number...

In fact, the ConTeXt output says "notes > internal error: note 1 of 'footnote' is not initialized"